# How can I use the COUNTA in ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've been trying to use ArrayFormula & COUNTA functions to achieve the result below:
[I want the result to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmGpo.png)

I want to count the number of the words in each field, and I am trying to drag formula down automatically when the sheet has new fields.  I came up with this formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(transpose(split(join(char(10),$A2),char(10)))))`

But when I add in new fields, the automation doesn't work. I also try to replace $A2 with $A2:A but I still couldn't automate it.
[The current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9O4R.png)

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that may work for you if you put this in `B2`:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="","",LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A&CHAR(10),"\S+(\n)","1"))))
```

Comment: Hi JvdV,
I put it in B2 and it really works! Thank you so much for this effective solution.